# Flutter word count in a text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the number of words in a text widget in flutter and display them for a user to know the word count in a particular text widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can regexp to find the number of spaces in the paragraph and +1 to it to get the count of a number of words. This will probably not work in the case of multiple paragraphs. But you can enhance the regex to modify it according to your use case.

```
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    RegExp regExp = RegExp(" ");
                    print(regExp.allMatches(value).length + 1);
                  },
                )
```